Persist list inside a object Django Rest Framework
I'm trying to persiste list of a python object (dico) like this but it's difficult
{
    "leader": {
        "nameLastname": "AAAAA"
    },
    "employeeRemun": {
        "grossSalaryBase": 111,
        "bonuses": 222,
        "travellingExpenses": 333,
        "noRemuneration": false
    },
    "abandonmentCurrentAccount": {
        "abandonDate": "2023-10-20",
        "partner": "BBB",
        "amount": 444,
        "recoveryDate": "2023-10-04",
        "recoveryAmount": 5555,
        "abortTime": "-16 jours"
    },
    "commentReviewDuring": {
        "review": "COMMENT DURING"
    },
    "commentReviewAfter": {
        "review": "COMMENT AFTER"
    },
    "list_benefits": [
        {
            "natureAvantage": {
                "actualAmount": 42354,
                "previousAmount": 53234
            },
            "leaderAvantage": {
                "nameLastname": "AAAAA"
            },
            "typeAvantage": {
                "benefitType": "Private Jet"
            }
        },
        {
            "natureAvantage": {
                "actualAmount": 43532,
                "previousAmount": 4324
            },
            "leaderAvantage": {
                "nameLastname": "AAAAA"
            },
            "typeAvantage": {
                "benefitType": "Rolls Royce"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Patch Methode:
At beginning i try to do this but i don't find how to access index of list ('HERE') :
I try to acces element inside the request with request.data.get(...) but for the natureAvantage it's not a {} but a [] need to be acces by a index
for indexLls in llsByIdSerialized.data['naturalBenefits']:
    benefitTypeById = AvantageNatureDirigeant.objects.get(id=indexLls)
    benefitRefresh = LeaderBenefeitTypeSerilizer(instance=benefitTypeById, data=request.data.get('remSection', {}).get('list_benefits', {}).get('natureAvantage', {}(''HERE index)))

    if benefitRefresh.is_valid():
        benefitRefresh.save()

So i try to do this one :
Create a seperated object
for index, benefit_data in enumerate(request.data.get('remSection', {}).get('list_benefits', [])):
    actual_amount = benefit_data.get('natureAvantage', {}).get('actualAmount')
    previous_amount = benefit_data.get('natureAvantage', {}).get('previousAmount')
    data_to_serialize = {
        'actualAmount': actual_amount,
        'previousAmount': previous_amount,
    }
    benefitTypeById = AvantageNatureDirigeant.objects.get(id=llsByIdSerialized.data['naturalBenefits'][index])

    benefit_refresh = LeaderBenefeitTypeSerilizer(instance=benefitTypeById,data=data_to_serialize)
    if benefit_refresh.is_valid():
        benefit_refresh.save()

But not working, have you an idea ?
